# How to change locale using JQuery UI datepicker in aurelia?

Tags: aurelia, jquery-ui-datepicker

Following is the code where jquery datepicker and i18n is included from jquery UI and a custom attribute is created. The datepicker works and shows the calendar, but it doesnt change the locale to french.
Is there any other way I should be including the locale files from jquery UI i18n folder.

```js
import $ from "jquery";
import {datepicker} from "components-jqueryui";
import {EventAggregator} from "aurelia-event-aggregator";
import {inject, customAttribute} from "aurelia-framework";
import {i18n} from "components-jqueryui";


@customAttribute("datepicker")

@inject(Element, EventAggregator)
export class DatePicker {
    constructor(element, eventAggregator) {
        this.element = element;

        // Handle to Aurelia pub/sub events
        this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    attached() {
        $(this.element).datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
        // $.datepicker.setDefaults(
        //     $.extend($.datepicker.regional["fr"])
        // );
        $(this.element).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", onClose: function fct() { this.focus(); }})
            .on("change", e => fireEvent(e.target, "input"));

        this.eventAggregator.subscribe("event:locale:changed", (locale) => {
            $(this.element).datepicker($.datepicker.regional["fr"]);
            // $.datepicker.setDefaults(
            //     $.extend($.datepicker.regional["fr"])
            // );
        });
    }

    detached() {
        $(this.element).datepicker("destroy")
            .off("change");
    }
}

function createEvent(name) {
    let event = document.createEvent("Event");

    event.initEvent(name, true, true);
    return event;
}

function fireEvent(element, name) {
    let event = createEvent(name);

    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import * as frCA from "components-jqueryui/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr-CA";

Set locale with:
$(this.element).datepicker($.datepicker.regional[locale]);

Comment: This will _set_ the locale, but not _changing_ it. With other words, it will recreate the component.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.datepicker` has a different interface for changing the locale, something like:

```
$(this.element).datepicker('options', 'new-locale');
```

Also, you need to import the corresponding localization script:

```
<script src="i18n/datepicker-fr.js"></script>
```

...or something equivalent ES6 import. Might be possible that your `import {i18n} from "components-jqueryui";` does this second part.

Full example here:
https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Although I need to include the translation files(datepicker-fr, etc.) in Aurelia which is not allowing the locale to load.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package you're working with, but maybe the the i18n import includes the localizations: `import {i18n} from "components-jqueryui";`

Comment: Thanks.  That import does not work as it is expecting a js file.
The following one works. :)

`import * as frCA from "components-jqueryui/ui/i18n/datepicker-fr-CA";`

also it is able to set locale with 
`$(this.element).datepicker($.datepicker.regional[locale]);`